# Dependency Property is not Accessable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary, dependency-properties

I'm getting an error in WPF XAML **Error 763    The member "FilterDictionary" is not recognized or is not accessible.   D:\Projects\Sample\Views\MainView.xaml**

My Dependency Property Source Code is

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterDictionaryProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FilterDictionary", typeof(Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<dynamic>>>), typeof(BListBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<dynamic>>> FilterDictionary
        {
            get { return (Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<dynamic>>>)GetValue(FilterDictionaryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FilterDictionaryProperty, value); }
        }
```

Kindly provide the Solution how to write the Custom Control Dependency Property. Is there is any wrong in my code?

The CheckedListItem Class Source is

```
public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool? isChecked;
        private string key;
        private Dictionary<string, dynamic> icon;
        private string stringFormat;
        private T item;
        private bool itemVisible = true;
        private bool? filterSortDirection = null;

        public CheckedListItem()
        { }

        public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
        {
            this.item = item;
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
        }

        public T Item
        {
            get { return item; }
            set
            {
                item = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
            }
        }

        public bool? IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
            }
        }

        public string Key
        {
            get { return key; }
            set
            {
                key = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Key"));
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, dynamic> IconDictionary
        {
            get { return icon; }
            set
            {
                icon = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IconDictionary"));
            }
        }

        public string StringFormat
        {
            get { return stringFormat; }
            set
            {
                stringFormat = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StringFormat"));
            }
        }

        public bool ItemVisible
        {
            get { return itemVisible; }
            set
            {
                itemVisible = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemVisible"));
            }
        }

        public bool? FilterSortDirection
        {
            get { return filterSortDirection; }
            set
            {
                filterSortDirection = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FilterSortDirection"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have property FilterDictionary defined for MainWindow?  Your code above shows that it is defined for BListBox.

Comment: And on which line is that?

Comment: BListBox is a Custom Control inherited from ListBox Control Class.

Comment: Can you post XAML code where you are using it?